# In which cases shlex.quote() is used?

Tags: python, shlex

I stumbled across [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote). I have read explanations about what [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) is, but I am wondering when to use it and when not. I see that I should use it when I am using Python as a subshell. For example, using `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()` or even using [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Should I use it when I am trying to check for a file using `os.path.isfile`, or are there any other useful ways to use it properly?